# How to install vite instead of create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, vite

**Language used** : javascript with react

**Problematic** : I am trying to use VITE instead of create-react-app but I got "This localhost page can’t be found" when I go on http://localhost:5173/.

How I have install vite :

```
npm create vite
√ Project name: ... client
√ Select a framework: » React
√ Select a variant: » JavaScript
cd client
npm i
npm run dev
```

**What I have tried** :

I have tried to config the vite.config file with this to change the port but still got the "This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:3000/"

*From*

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

*To*

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import dns from 'dns';

dns.setDefaultResultOrder('verbatim');

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
  },
});
enter code here
```